# Я не ем суп — напротив, я только тыквенную мякоть из него вылавливая(,) ем

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Я не ем суп — напротив, я только тыквенную мякоть из него вылавливая(,) ем.

Answer (score 3):

Надо записать так:

*Я не ем **сам тыквенный** суп — напротив, я только **тыквенную** мякоть, **из него вылавливая**, ем.*

Деепричастный оборот обособляется.

Comment: Please, do not rephrase my sentences.

Comment: Please write the right suggestions. Then I won't have to rephrase them.

Comment: I believe the first comma is not needed.

Comment: Предложение: Я только тыквенную мякоть / из супа вылавливая / ем.  Оборот обособляется, какие уж тут сомнения?

Comment: *Вылавливая* и *ем* имеют общее дополние — *мякоть*.

Comment: Может, он подразумевал под оборотом не только это? Может, вот это — _только тыквенную мякоть из супа вылавлявая_ — он имел в виду под целым оборотом. Впрочем, мне нравится предложенный вами вариант. Ставлю третий плюс.

Comment: Спасибо, Максим. Отчасти меня это утешит))  Но автору не нравятся мои ответы, увы)  Я же стараюсь не иметь в виду, а записывать нормальную речь с конкретным смыслом.